# Хранить картинку в памяти телефона

Tags: java, android, picasso

Есть огромный массив с данными и картинками, после каждого раза входа в приложению заново загружает все картинки с интернета, что сделать чтобы после перезапуска снова с интернета не загружал?

```
    if(language.getName()=="English") {
        holder.myTextView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(20);
        holder.myTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_check_box_black_24dp, 0);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
            holder.myTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_city_red);
        }
    }

    //для работы с картинками
    Picasso.with(context).load(language.getIcon()).placeholder(R.drawable.logo_small).into(holder.img);
```

Comment: А вы "гуглили"?

Comment: опишите проблему с которой столкнулись, что не получилось сделать, можно писать в БД, можно писать в кеш приложения, можно в память, можно на карту. и все реализации будут отличаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так с [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

```
Glide.with(this) 
    .load("http://myAva.jpg") 
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE) 
    .into(imageView);
```